# Print column name, count and sum if the values is greater then zero

Tags: mysql

I would like to count and sum of item whose value is greater than zero. The following data and example are shown below... I am unable to get data in this format.

Original data

```
---------------------------------------
Id      Item_1  Item_2  Item_3  Item_4
---------------------------------------
1         0       500     0        0
2         200     0       0        0
3         350     0       0        0
4         0       0      500       0
5         0       300    0         0
6         0       0      0        400
7         0       0      200      0
---------------------------------------
```

I want in this format

```
--------------------
Count   ITEM    SUM
--------------------
2       Item_1  550
2       Item_2  800
2       Item_3  700
1       Item_4  400
```

Comment: Your data is not normalized. You should change your table design

Comment: As juergen d said. Otherwise you need 4 Queries or you combine the queries with UNION

Comment: Sir, could we use case, when and then?

Comment: design change is recommended, but if you have just these 4 specific columns, we can provide solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query with this design:

```
select count(Item_1) as Count, 'Item_1' as ITEM, sum(Item_1) as SUM from table_name
UNION
select count(Item_2) as Count, 'Item_2' as ITEM, sum(Item_2) as SUM from table_name
UNION
select count(Item_3) as Count, 'Item_3' as ITEM, sum(Item_3) as SUM from table_name
UNION
select count(Item_4) as Count, 'Item_4' as ITEM, sum(Item_4) as SUM from table_name
```

But table design is not proper. It should be something like below:

```
create table my_table
(id int, item_name varchar(50), item_sold int);
```

Then you can use case statement to compare item_name.

Comment: add `where Item_# > 0` otherwise count will return wrong value

Comment: @manishyadav: Please accept this as correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please normalize the db at least below.

items table

```
--------------
id      item
--------------
1       Item 1 
2       Item 2  
3       Item 3
--------------
```

items_values Table

```
--------------------------
id    item_id   item_value
--------------------------
1       1            0
2       1          200
3       3          350
--------------------------
```

Then you can simply get your result like below.

```
SELECT COUNT(items_values.item_value) AS ValueCount, items.item, SUM(items_values.item_value) FROM items_values
INNER JOIN items ON items_values.item_id = items.id
GROUP BY items.id;
```